# UITableViewCell next to eachother

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can i make a tableview where the cells are next to each other. Where there are 2 on each row. example like this? In the second row there are 2 images next to each other. Can this be done in a tableview by making custom tablevieCells?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this can be done in UItableViewCell But preferred to use collection view for this kind of view.

Just subclass uitableviewcell, add new method

```
-(void)setCellWithNumberOfImages:(NSInteger)images withImage1:(UIimage *)image1 withImage2:(UIImage *)image2;
if(image2 ==nil)
//add only one UIimageView with image1
else
//add two imageviews.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a UICollectionViewController (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html)

Using a UICollectionView you can implement a custom layout which layouts the elements as in your screenshot

Answer (score 0):

You can Use UICOllectionView That's much easier and customizable, you can chose how many item you want to have in a row and size for example.

for more information please check: UICollectionView Class Reference